# I downloaded an Armory .msi and the checksum failed. What should I do? (Windows)

Tags: installation, armory

I downloaded Armory from [here](http://bitcoinarmory.googlecode.com/files/armory_0.88.1-beta_win64.msi) and the checksum file from [here](https://bitcoinarmory.googlecode.com/files/armory_0.88.1-beta_sha256.txt.asc) using the links from [the main installation page](https://bitcoinarmory.com/get-armory/). I downloaded the Win64 .msi installer.

From there, I used a Cygwin prompt and [fciv](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) to verify the download. I didn't feel like downloading keys, etc., so I just looked at the checksum in the .txt.asc file, and compared the first few characters to the fciv output. As you can see, there's a mismatch.

```
Alex Jordan@ajordan /cygdrive/c/Users/SAAS Student/Downloads
$ cat armory_0.88.1-beta_sha256.txt.asc
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

3d7f620c028940540dc48d41a9cf6127f7f42b920664de4a957fc407b3f59abf  armory_0.88.1-beta_amd64.deb
670b74ade48b041bd376512f5e2db78075d794495ef347bf0b792156c9a90048  armory_0.88.1-beta_i386.deb
087fc8a49de3f32fb140151d9c277f9810919f751bf754f0823da084cb67810f  armory_0.88.1-beta_OfflineBundle_Ubuntu-10.04-32bit.tar.gz
3a86a57208c015adce086e9c300beb56592979b908ec2731bd2f267efa7aaf28  armory_0.88.1-beta_OfflineBundle_Ubuntu-10.04-64bit.tar.gz
a730df751c753bdd2664d1e0b32a3ff138494900040c742b0ebfced3b516fad6  armory_0.88.1-beta_OSX.dmg
4d14b43ed75194a753dc202d70f9650a92d7b8756c917fe82a7f46ecd3466aa1  armory_0.88.1-beta_win32.msi
26735a99948ac1402242e83f0c18aed4477b132654d1a94d7968caa0e72790df  armory_0.88.1-beta_win64.msi

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.10 (GNU/Linux)
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=mOdM
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

Alex Jordan@ajordan /cygdrive/c/Users/SAAS Student/Downloads
$ fciv -sha1 armory_0.88.1-beta_win64.msi
//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
d86ccbf4d709c04ba6250a94782ea620ab0c26fd armory_0.88.1-beta_win64.msi

Alex Jordan@ajordan /cygdrive/c/Users/SAAS Student/Downloads
$
```

How should I proceed? Is it safe to install anyway, probably because I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a SHA256 hash. Try `fciv -sha256` or `sha256sum`.

Comment: seems like fciv doesn't do anything but SHA1 and MD5: http://pastebin.com/VTDNSsRG

Comment: You could also try this http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Burning_ISO_images_to_disc/sect-Burning_ISO_images_to_disc-Validating_the_Files-Validating_at_the_Windows_Command_Prompt.html